# Solr 4.5, timeouts on cold cache, how to keep it warm?

Tags: cache, solr

(not sure if that is more StackOverflow kind of question so pardon me if it is)

There is an fairly large index of about 70M documents roughly 30Gb in size running on Solr 4.5. While it is fine with simple queries, complex ones involving faceting or aggregated stats cause timeouts if called after a long delay.

If you wait for about 5 minutes after such a timeout then the same query repeated and other similar ones (not exactly the same but using the same functions) run fine which I guess happens because the cache is now warm.

My question is to how to keep the cache warm for longer as it isn't clear to me which config parameters should be tweaked. I know, for example, an autowarming query can be specified in config, but don't know how to make it use facets or StatsComponent so it warms what my queries need.

I have changed `autowarmCount` attribute of all `<documentCache>` tags in my `solrconfig.xml` from 0 to 100, but it didn't seem to have any noticeable effect.

I understand that might one of those RTFM questions, but reading through [SolrCaching wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching) didn't help much, so any advice is welcome.